# Perl variable inside a HREF

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Is it possible to have a variable inside a href HTML link? In other words, could I dynamically generate a series of html links by iterating through an array?

For example, like in this Perl CGI extract:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
value=array
<A href="prog1.cgi?data=${value}">$value</A>
}
```

I am using a different query string value in the link each iteration of the loop. If this is not possible, I would appreciate any other advice.

Comment: You seem to have confused perl and html. Do you mean to have some sort of print statement?

Comment: yaaaa....  the href comes inside the print statement

Comment: #!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w use strict; use warnings; use Fcntl; print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>List of files</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>"; my $dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\DailyStatusReports'; my @items; my $final; opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!; while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) { push (@items,$file); } foreach my $file (@items) { $final=$file; } print qq[<a href="../DailyStatusReports/mailto:$final">$final</a>]; print "</BODY></HTML>"; closedir(DIR); exit 0;

Comment: The above is my perl code... i want to make a html link of the last file in the folder... wen i click tat html link it should open the html file.... the error that comes is that "Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. " am using xampp in apache server

Answer (score 4):

The HTML is to be printed, so we're simply talking about concatenation. Don't forget to convert your text to the proper format first, though.

```
use CGI         qw( escapeHTML );
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );

for my $value (@array) {
   my $uri = 'prog1.cgi?data='.uri_escape($value);
   my $html = escapeHTML($value);
   print qq{<a href="$uri">$html</a>};
}
```

or

```
use CGI         qw( escapeHTML );
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );

for my $value (@array) {
   printf '<a href="prog1.cgi?data=%s">%s</a>',
      uri_escape($value),
      escapeHTML($value);
}
```

Comment: Good thing to escape strings.

Comment: #!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>List of files</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";
my $dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\DailyStatusReports';
my @items;
my $final;
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) 
{
push (@items,$file);
}

foreach my $file (@items)
{
  $final=$file;
}

print qq[<a href="../DailyStatusReports/mailto:$final">$final</a>];
#print $final;
#print ".html">Latest Test Results</a> \n";

#print ">Latest Test Results</a> \n";  
print "</BODY></HTML>";  

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;

Comment: The above is my perl code... i want to make a html link of the last file in the folder... wen i click tat html link it should open the html file.... the error that comes is that "Access forbidden!
 
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
 "    am using xampp in apache server

Comment: That's unreadable. If you need to update your question, update your question. Feel free to let me know what you have something readable (using "*@ikegami, I updated my question*"). However, it sounds like you are trying to ask a completely new question. If that's the case, post it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the value within a print:

```
for my $value (@array) {
    printf '<A href="prog1.cgi?data=%s">%s</A>', $value, $value;
}
```